# How can I merge two Python dictionaries in a single expression, adding up the elements with the same keys in both dicts?

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is very similar to [How to merge two Python dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-can-i-merge-union-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)

However if my dicts are:

```
x = {'a':1, 'b': 2}
y = {'b':10, 'c': 11}
```

and my 'merged' dict is z

Then I would want:

```
print(z)
```

to output:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 12, 'c': 11}
```

(Whereas in the linked question z's b key would have a value of 10)

Comment: What rule determines that you want `'b': 12`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters When [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders) is implemented, closing will happen immediately :-)

Comment: Sorry about the duplicate, thanks for the link.

Comment: @thefourtheye: *If* it were to happen; it's a big change.